# Ошибка при использовании метода 1 класса во 2 классе

Tags: java, android, методы

```
public LinearLayout LayoutOfScroll;
public EditText edBudget;
public TextView tvZatrati;
public TextView tvOstatok;
public FloatingActionButton fab_add;
public int Budget = 0;                    
public int Zatrati = 0;                  
public int Ostatok = 0;                  
public String etAlertDialod;
```

Метод очистки в 1 классе:

```
public void FAB_clear_method(){
    LayoutOfScroll.removeAllViews();    
    Budget = 0;                         
    edBudget.setText("");               
    Zatrati = 0;                  
    tvZatrati.setText("0");             
    Ostatok = 0;                       
    tvOstatok.setText("0");             
}
```

Использование этого метода  во 2 классе:

```
ContentFragment object = new ContentFragment();  
object.FAB_clear_method();
```

Код ошибки:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.evgeny.ShoppingBudget, PID: 3705
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.removeAllViews()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.evgeny.ShoppingBudget.fragments.ContentFragment.FAB_clear_method(ContentFragment.java:151)
        at com.example.evgeny.ShoppingBudget.fragments.SavedListsFragment.onItemClick(SavedListsFragment.java:63)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1145)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3042)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3879)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.removeAllViews()' on a null object reference    говорит что ссылается на нулевой объект.

Comment: `LayoutOfScroll` у вас null. Покажите код, где вы его инициализируете.

Comment: вот так я его инициализирую:public LinearLayout LayoutOfScroll; LayoutOfScroll = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.LayoutOfScroll);

Comment: Либо в вашей разметке нет вью с таким id, либо вы вызываете метод до того, как переменная проинициализирована. Добавьте к вопросу полный код фрагмента и xml разметку к нему.

Comment: Вы создаете новый фрагмент, который не привязан к активити, который даже не отображается на экране, и пытаетесь вызвать у него метод для очистки вью. Естественно у вас ничего не заработает. Надо вызывать этот метод у фрагмента который уже существует и отображается на экране, а не создавать новый, вызывать у него метод и надеяться что все заработает.

Comment: Суть ясна. Но как мне вызвать этот метод у уже существующего фрагмента? Как его отыскать?

Comment: Через `findFragmenByTag() ` например